# READING CHARACTER FROM CURSOR

Tags: assembly

I am working on a video application in assembly. I use this code to get into video mode

```
mov ah,0      
mov al,13h
int 10h
```

then I'm writing using PRINT (because I'm using emu8086)

```
mov ah,02h
mov dh,1
mov dl,1 
int 10h  
mov ax,0h
mov ax,[bp]
mov ah,0 
call print_num
```

then I'm trying to read the character in dh, 1 dl,1 that should be the char from the matrix
with

```
mov ah,02h
mov dh,1 
mov dl,1
int 10h 

mov ah,08h
int 10h
sub al,'0'
```

but I'm getting `al = 00` before `sub al,'0'` and `al = D0h` after this line when it should be 4 or 5 depending the matrix

what am I doing wrong? Or can't I get the char in this video mode?

Comment: What processor? Are you using an OS?

Comment: @RedX The OP claimed to use emu8086. That tells it all. @user2934142 How about circumventing BIOS and using a custom video driver? Video memory by default starts at `0B8000h`. It is pretty straightforward to write a driver for 80x25 text mode. Please also note that it actually rarely makes sense to read a char from the screen (that's an *output* device).

Comment: You could keep track of which characters you have written to the screen yourself by storing them in an array. I don't know what the text resolution is like in mode 13h, but even if the characters are 8x8 pixels that's still only 1000 bytes you need to keep track of (or maybe double that if you also want the color of each character).

Comment: Screen memory in text mode starts at 0B8000h, but mode 13h (graphics) starts at 0A0000h. `[bp]` defaults to `[ss:bp]`. I don't know if either of these is a "problem"...

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that you're selecting mode 13h, which I believe is 320x200x8bpp?  The BIOS getchar routines only function in text modes.  They don't contain the logic to map pixels from graphics modes back into characters.  You'd have to write that yourself.